# Openpyxl errno 2: saying no such file or directory, but do

Tags: python, openpyxl

SOLVED: My idle was bad or something. Installed another idle, visual studio. I checked path and moved file there. Works now.

What am I doing wrong. Is the file not in the working directory??

Am I not in the working directory? I have the file in the python path. Does it need to be in the scripts?

```
>>> from openpyxl import load_workbook



>>> wb = load_workbook(filename = 'BUDGET.xlsx')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    wb = load_workbook(filename = 'BUDGET.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 316, in load_workbook
    data_only, keep_links)
  File "C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1207, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'BUDGET.xlsx'
```

Comment: Use the absolute path to avoid such issues

Comment: ***"Is the file not in the working directory?"***: YES, ***"Am I not in the working directory?"***: [`print(os.getcwd())`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd), ***"I have the file in the python path"***: WRONG, ***"Does it need to be in the scripts?"***: NO

Comment: Fixed it. Idle must have been the issue. I download visual studio and got the path and moved my file there and bam. working.

Comment: @crein147 you can add an answer to your own question. Please, review https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer and just improve the site!!